# A string não veio vazia então chama outra tela Android

Tags: android, android-activity

O objetivo da aplicação Android é o seguinte;

Carreguei estaticamente uma lista de pessoas na entidade Pessoa, então a classe tela_activity iria identificar se a lista iria vim vazia ou preenchida, se viesse vazia ela iria chamar tela_principal.xml se viesse preenchida iria carregar cadastro_activity.xml

Eu tentei fazer isso mas ao executar a aplicação ele me retornou esse erro;

```
04-30 16:07:34.836 4729-4729/br.com.wlady.personalfinan E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: br.com.wlady.personalfinan, PID: 4729
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.wlady.personalfinan/br.com.wlady.personalfinan.tela_activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
                                                                              at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:398)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
                                                                              at br.com.wlady.personalfinan.tela_activity.onCreate(tela_activity.java:22)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
04-30 16:07:41.259 4729-4729/br.com.wlady.personalfinan I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4729 SIG: 9
```

**Eu não quero somente entender o erro queria que me ajudassem a como consertar esse problema.**

Entidade Pessoa

```
public class Pessoa {

    private String login;
    private String senha;
    private String email;


    public Pessoa(String login, String senha, String email) {
        this.login = login;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public static List<Pessoa> getPessoa(){
        List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();
        pessoas.add((new Pessoa("wlady","1234","tecnico100@gmail.com")));
        return pessoas;
    }

}
```

Tela Principal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Dados Pessoais"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_nome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edit_nome"
        android:text="Login" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_nome"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_email"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_nome" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edit_email"
        android:text="E-mail" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_email"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_nome"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_email"
        android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_email"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Resistrar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Tela de cadastro

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity que chama a as telas

```
public class tela_activity extends ListActivity {
    private PessoaAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        adapter = new PessoaAdapter(this, Pessoa.getPessoa());
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        if (!adapter.isEmpty()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.tela_principal);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.cadastro_activity);
        }
    }
}
```

=======================================

```
public class cadastro_activity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cadastro_activity);

    }
}
```

========================================

Código adicional

```
public class PessoaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Pessoa> pessoas;
    private LayoutInflater innflater;


    public PessoaAdapter(Context context, List<Pessoa> pessoas){
        this.pessoas = pessoas;
        innflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pessoas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return pessoas.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Arquivo AndroidManisfest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="br.com.wlady.personalfinan">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".tela_activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Estrutura do projeto
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o que diz o erro, é necessário que seu `contentView` deve possuir uma ListView declarada com o atributo id igual a `android.R.id.list`.

Acredito que para personalizar a lista (e adapter) deve se criar um layout específico:

Segue um exemplo:

**custom_list_activity_view.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">

     <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>


 </LinearLayout>
```

**MyListAdapter.java**

```
 public class MyListAdapter extends ListActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


         setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_activity_view);


     }
 }
```